# How to create bundle if variable not initialized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

How to create bundle if variable not initialized?

```
var widget = {
  init: function(){thmh}
}
```

If i dont initialized variable widget

```
widget.init()
```

Webpack misses this module widget when i create bundle, how to off all misses modules? 
My modules init on Html page. I cant init they in JS file.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the widget directly within your build? Are you running Uglify as part of your Webpack process?

Comment: Yes, i need init my widget only in html file. I think i dont use Uglify. This is my webpack.config.js

https://pastebin.com/Nc5mzRjr